# Looping Through Column and Saving Resultant into new column

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to save a result of a for loop as it goes through each row.

For example if you have A1:A45 filled with values and you want to add 6 to each cell in that range and output the resultant for each operation into column B.

I am just missing the portion that gets the for loop to output into a new column for every operation performed. I think from there I can troubleshoot and google tutorials.

This is a snippet of a macro I am making. After my concatenation operation I would like to save the new string to a new column and as it goes through the loop, the resultant string would save sequentially.

```
Select Case numCav
    Case Is = 4
    For a = 2 To lastUserDim1
            For cavNum = 1 To 4
                newDimName = .Cells(a, 1).Value2 & "_Cav" & cavNum
                .Cells(a, 8) = newDimName
            Next cavNum
    Next a
```

Comment: `.Cells(a, 8) = newDimName` - you're overwriting the same cell inside your `For cavNum = 1 To 4` loop. Not sure what the intended behavior is.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am looking for direction on how to output the values without over writing them. I'm looking for the logic (coding scheme) behind my question so I can understand it better for immediate and future use. The intended behavior was phrased in my question.

Comment: I don't understand *where* the values are supposed to be output. What exactly does `output the resultant for each operation into column B` mean? That cells in column B get populated one after another?

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm missing that portion.

Comment: `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = newDimName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to output the `newDimName` into the next available cell in column 8, then you can use `.End(xlUp)`:

```
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = newDimName
```

All this is doing is starting from the very bottom of column 8 (`Rows.Count` is the number of the last row), then going up (equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd>), then `Offset`ting one to the next row.

Comment: I see, yes that makes sense. Many thanks! I want to be able to understand so I can have this logic in my head for future use.

Comment: @JGuy - you may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba), which is about finding the last cell, and discusses `End(xlUp)` in more detail.